# Adding BigQuery connection with gdrive scopes?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I have an external Sheets table that I want to query via the BigQueryOperator in Airflow.

I would prefer to use the Cloud Composer service account.

I've created a new connection via the Airflow UI with the following parameters:

```
Conn Id: bigquery_with_gdrive_scope
Conn Type: google_cloud_platform
Project Id: <my project id>
Keyfile path: <none>
Keyfile JSON: <none>
Scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

In my DAG, I use: `BigQueryOperator(..., bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_with_gdrive_scope')`

The log reports: `Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.`

The task attributes show: `bigquery_conn_id     bigquery_with_gdrive_scope`

It's almost as though the `bigquery_conn_id` parameter is being ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone runs up against the same problem, (Composer 1.0.0,  Airflow 1.9.0) falls back to `gcloud auth` unless `Keyfile path` or `Keyfile json` are provided. This ignores any scope arguments.

The master branch of Airflow fixes this; but for now you have to generate a credential file for the service account and tell Airflow where these are located.

There are step by step directions [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_new_airflow_connections).

For my use-case I created a key for airflow's service account and set up a connection as follows:

```
Conn Id: bigquery_with_gdrive_scope
Conn Type: google_cloud_platform
Project Id: <my project id>
Keyfile path: <none>
Keyfile JSON: <contents of keyfile for airflow service account>
Scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding GCP API scopes (like in the accepted answer) did not work for us. After a lot of debugging, it seemed like GCP had "root" scopes that were assigned to the environment during creation, and could not be overridden via Airflow Connections. It seems like this only affects GCP API scopes.

For reference, we were using `composer 1.4.0` and `airflow 1.10.0`

If you want to add a scope pertaining to GCP on Cloud Composer, you MUST do so when you [create the environment](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating). It cannot be modified after the fact.

When creating your environment, be sure to add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`. Specifically, you can add the following flag to your `gcloud composer environment create` command:

`--oauth-scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

Lastly, do not forget to share the document with the service account email (unless you have given the service account domain wide access)

Comment: awesome many thanks. I wish I had found this answer much earlier