# failed to retrieve data from big query with external source table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I tried to retrieve bigquery data using appscript. the data is external data that comes from a spreadsheet. but it failed and got an error as below.

```
    GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.
```

for information, bigquery, spreadsheet, and appscript are in the same project and account. here's the code I used

```
    /**
 * Runs a BigQuery query and logs the results in a spreadsheet.
 */
function runQuery() {
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  const projectId = 'myProject';

  const request = {
    // TODO (developer) - Replace query with yours
    query: 'SELECT * ' +
      'FROM `myProject.myDataset.myTable` ',
    useLegacySql: false
  };
  let queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  const jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  let sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  let rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }

  if (!rows) {
    console.log('No rows returned.');
    return;
  }
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('BigQuery Results');
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Append the headers.
  const headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.name;
  });
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  // Append the results.
  const data = new Array(rows.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const cols = rows[i].f;
    data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
    for (let j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(data);

  console.log('Results spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
}
```

I realized the problem is in the table whose source is external. because when trying with the public dataset, the code runs fine. what causes the problem to appear?

Comment: I seem to remember reading somewhere that the identity making the BQ request needs to have the OAuth scope for Drive ... see for example .... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-auth-drive-scope and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753952/adding-bigquery-connection-with-gdrive-scopes